Unable to update/query local user profile if LDAP connection fails for Keycloak
I have integrated keycloak with my application, and have added a LDAP connection. When the LDAP Connection is correctly added things work smooth and as expected. However, if there is an issue with LDAP Connection then user profile update/ user query fails even for Local users(Realm users).
On version 25.0.2 and 25.0.6
I created a "test" user but only provided username and password. When tried to login through the keycloak login ui, it got redirected to required-action screen and asked for email, firstname and lastname. Upon entering these fields got a error on the screen and below logs in the logs.
2024-09-30 06:58:13,617 ERROR [org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.store.ldap.LDAPOperationManager] (executor-thread-7) Could not query server using DN [ou=myldap,o=test.com] and filter [(&(|(dept=00E640)(dept=B2C))(mail=test@admin.com)(objectclass=organizationalPerson))]: javax.naming.InterruptedNamingException: Interrupted while waiting for the connection pool lock
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.Connections.grabLock(Connections.java:366)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.Pool.getPooledConnection(Pool.java:140)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapPoolManager.getLdapClient(LdapPoolManager.java:341)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.getInstance(LdapClient.java:1608)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2848)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.(LdapCtx.java:348)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxFromUrl(LdapCtxFactory.java:229)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:189)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:247)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:154)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:84)
at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:732)
at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:305)
at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:236)
at java.naming/javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.(InitialLdapContext.java:154)
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.store.ldap.LDAPContextManager.createLdapContext(LDAPContextManager.java:74)
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.store.ldap.LDAPContextManager.getLdapContext(LDAPContextManager.java:93)
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.store.ldap.LDAPOperationManager.execute(LDAPOperationManager.java:709)
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.store.ldap.LDAPOperationManager.execute(LDAPOperationManager.java:704)
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.store.ldap.LDAPOperationManager.search(LDAPOperationManager.java:255)
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.store.ldap.LDAPIdentityStore.fetchQueryResults(LDAPIdentityStore.java:278)
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.query.internal.LDAPQuery.getResultList(LDAPQuery.java:174)
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.query.internal.LDAPQuery.getFirstResult(LDAPQuery.java:185)
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPStorageProvider.queryByEmail(LDAPStorageProvider.java:745)
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPStorageProvider.getUserByEmail(LDAPStorageProvider.java:752)
at org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageManager.lambda$getUserByEmail$20(UserStorageManager.java:426)
at org.keycloak.utils.ServicesUtils.lambda$timeBoundOne$1(ServicesUtils.java:83)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$RefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:400)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:528)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
at org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageManager.getUserByEmail(UserStorageManager.java:426)
at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.UserCacheSession.getUserByEmail(UserCacheSession.java:419)
at org.keycloak.userprofile.validator.DuplicateEmailValidator.validate(DuplicateEmailValidator.java:70)
at org.keycloak.userprofile.AttributeValidatorMetadata.validate(AttributeValidatorMetadata.java:80)
at org.keycloak.userprofile.DefaultAttributes.validate(DefaultAttributes.java:169)
at org.keycloak.userprofile.DefaultUserProfile.validate(DefaultUserProfile.java:76)
at org.keycloak.userprofile.DefaultUserProfile.update(DefaultUserProfile.java:104)
at org.keycloak.authentication.requiredactions.UpdateProfile.processAction(UpdateProfile.java:75)
at org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.processRequireAction(LoginActionsService.java:1156)
at org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.requiredActionPOST(LoginActionsService.java:1090)
at org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService$quarkusrestinvoker$requiredActionPOST_02b0bc04a277d23515b0317d630ef043b756d133.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.InvocationHandler.handle(InvocationHandler.java:29)
at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:141)
at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:147)
at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:582)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

2024-09-30 06:58:13,619 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (executor-thread-7) Uncaught server error: org.keycloak.models.ModelException: LDAP Query failed
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.query.internal.LDAPQuery.getResultList(LDAPQuery.java:178)
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.query.internal.LDAPQuery.getFirstResult(LDAPQuery.java:185)
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPStorageProvider.queryByEmail(LDAPStorageProvider.java:745)
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.LDAPStorageProvider.getUserByEmail(LDAPStorageProvider.java:752)
at org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageManager.lambda$getUserByEmail$20(UserStorageManager.java:426)
at org.keycloak.utils.ServicesUtils.lambda$timeBoundOne$1(ServicesUtils.java:83)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$RefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:400)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:528)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
at org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageManager.getUserByEmail(UserStorageManager.java:426)
at org.keycloak.models.cache.infinispan.UserCacheSession.getUserByEmail(UserCacheSession.java:419)
at org.keycloak.userprofile.validator.DuplicateEmailValidator.validate(DuplicateEmailValidator.java:70)
at org.keycloak.userprofile.AttributeValidatorMetadata.validate(AttributeValidatorMetadata.java:80)
at org.keycloak.userprofile.DefaultAttributes.validate(DefaultAttributes.java:169)
at org.keycloak.userprofile.DefaultUserProfile.validate(DefaultUserProfile.java:76)
at org.keycloak.userprofile.DefaultUserProfile.update(DefaultUserProfile.java:104)
at org.keycloak.authentication.requiredactions.UpdateProfile.processAction(UpdateProfile.java:75)
at org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.processRequireAction(LoginActionsService.java:1156)
at org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService.requiredActionPOST(LoginActionsService.java:1090)
at org.keycloak.services.resources.LoginActionsService$quarkusrestinvoker$requiredActionPOST_02b0bc04a277d23515b0317d630ef043b756d133.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.InvocationHandler.handle(InvocationHandler.java:29)
at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:141)
at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:147)
at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:582)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused by: org.keycloak.models.ModelException: Querying of LDAP failed org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.query.internal.LDAPQuery@3f9d2d87
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.store.ldap.LDAPIdentityStore.fetchQueryResults(LDAPIdentityStore.java:294)
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.query.internal.LDAPQuery.getResultList(LDAPQuery.java:174)
... 38 more
Caused by: javax.naming.InterruptedNamingException: Interrupted while waiting for the connection pool lock
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.Connections.grabLock(Connections.java:366)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.pool.Pool.getPooledConnection(Pool.java:140)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapPoolManager.getLdapClient(LdapPoolManager.java:341)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.getInstance(LdapClient.java:1608)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2848)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.(LdapCtx.java:348)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxFromUrl(LdapCtxFactory.java:229)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:189)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:247)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:154)
at java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:84)
at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:732)
at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:305)
at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:236)
at java.naming/javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.(InitialLdapContext.java:154)
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.store.ldap.LDAPContextManager.createLdapContext(LDAPContextManager.java:74)
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.store.ldap.LDAPContextManager.getLdapContext(LDAPContextManager.java:93)
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.store.ldap.LDAPOperationManager.execute(LDAPOperationManager.java:709)
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.store.ldap.LDAPOperationManager.execute(LDAPOperationManager.java:704)
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.store.ldap.LDAPOperationManager.search(LDAPOperationManager.java:255)
at org.keycloak.storage.ldap.idm.store.ldap.LDAPIdentityStore.fetchQueryResults(LDAPIdentityStore.java:278)
... 39 more

Similar behavior is observered in 23.0.5
Additionally the following API also fails for both the version if the LDAP is wrongly configured
URI : https:///admin/realms/myrealm/users?first=0&max=11&search=*
Version
25.0.2, 25.0.6 and 23.0.3

The question is tagged with Realm, part of MongoDB Realm the database. Can you clarify how it ties in?

Hey @Jay, here the realm I am referring to is a keycloak realm, looks like this is a wrong tag, let me remove the tag to avoid confusion. Thanks
